# Zeros in FIR Filter

Tags: finite-impulse-response, poles-zeros

I recently had this question in a quiz and was quite confused as I don't think I can assume there are more zeros from just one, so how should I interpret it?

Assuming a linear phase FIR filter with real value coefficients and a zero at $2e^{j0.5\pi}$, which of these is true?

a)There are another 3 zeros at $2e^{-j0.5\pi}$ , $0.5e^{j0.5\pi}$ and $0.5e^{-j0.5\pi}$

---

b)There are more than 3 other zeros.

---

c)Theres just another zero at $2e^{-j0.5\pi}$

---

d)All the zeros in the filter are within the unit circle

Thank you

Comment: why do you assume you can? There's more to this problem than you're telling us!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi Marcus. It was a multiple answer in my last test an the options where that there were either multiple more zeros like 3 or more or just one. As it was a very weirdly posed question I don't really know if I can assume the filter to have more zeros or not

Comment: Can you reproduce the actual wording of the question. It seems to me there was a hint in how the question was worded, but you don't "transport" that hint. Generally, I don't think any statement but symmetrical spectrum from the real-valuedness can be inferred.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'll try to change it up to be more readable thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For a real value FIR filter, all its zeros should be conjugate pairs. So $2e^{-j0.5π}$ is also a zero.
2. For a linear phase FIR filter, it should satisfy $h(n) = \pm h(N - 1 - n)$, and its transfer function equals to
   $$
   H(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} h(n)z^{-n} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \pm h(N - 1 - n)z^{-n}
   $$
   Let $m = N-1-n$, we can derive
   $$
   H(z) = \sum_{m=0}^{N-1} \pm h(m)z^{-(N-1-m)} = \pm z^{-(N-1)} \sum_{m=0}^{N-1} h(m)z^{-m} = \pm z^{-(N-1)} H(z^{-1})
   $$
   Therefore, if $z=2e^{j0.5π}$ is a zero, $z^{-1} = 0.5e^{-j0.5π}$ must be a zero. And according to the first point, $0.5e^{j0.5\pi}$ is also a zero.

Comment: Thank you. So the 0.5 comes from -(0.5-1) right?

Comment: @HelpMeBro which 0.5? The reciprocal of a complex number $z = re^{j\theta}$ equals to $z^{-1} = \frac{1}{r} e^{-j\theta}$.